# Forcing a kernel module's GPIOs to always be outputs

Tags: linux-kernel, gpio, i2c

I'm writing a driver for the pca9570 i2c GPO expander.  (It has four output bits, whose values are set by a simple one-byte write to its i2c address.)

I'm currently setting up the GPIO as follows:

```
struct gpio_chip *gc = &chip->gpio_chip;

gc->set = pca9570_gpio_set_value;
gc->get = pca9570_gpio_get_value;
gc->direction_output = pca9570_gpio_direction_output;
gc->direction_input = pca9570_gpio_direction_input;

gc->can_sleep = true;

gc->base = gpio_start;
gc->ngpio = PCA9570_GPIO_COUNT;
gc->label = chip->client->name;
gc->owner = THIS_MODULE;

gc->dev = &chip->client->dev;
```

How can this module tell the kernel that it can only output data?  i.e. I want the result of user-space `root@arm:/sys/class/gpio/gpio508# cat direction` to be `out`, not `in` as it currently is.

I'm half-thinking that this driver needs to add some client-side gpio calls to set the direction as output on initialisation, and whenever a user tries to set them as inputs.  Is this the correct way to do it?

Are there any existing "output only" gpio drivers which I could copy?

Comment: *"Is this the correct way to do it?"* -- No.  If you have well-behaved code that properly used resource control (e.g. `gpio_request()`), then your driver would own the GPIO pin, and nothing else would try to change the direction.

Comment: @sawdust, I think you meant `gpiod_get()`, since `gpio_request()` is quite legacy API and maintainers discourage to use latter.

Comment: According to the datasheet http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA9570.pdf the expander supports Input and Output. So, you don't need to enforce anything in the driver, this is caller's busyness, not yours.

Comment: @sawdust The module is providing the gpio pins, not consuming them.

Comment: @0andriy The PCA9570 does *not* provide inputs.  The only thing that can be read is the state of the outputs.  Perhaps that's worthwhile?

Comment: @chrisdew I stand corrected *All ports are outputs and cannot be used as inputs*. Okay, in this case do not provide callbacks, you will get what you want. I  will do the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to datasheet http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA9570.pdf *The PCA9570 is a CMOS device that provides 4 bits of General Purpose parallel Output (GPO) expansion in low voltage processor and handheld battery powered mobile applications.*

To satisfy this requirement the driver in Linux kernel must not implement `->get_direction()` and `->direction_input()` callbacks as stated in the code:

```
            if (chip->get_direction) {
             ...
            } else if (!chip->direction_input) {
                    /*
                     * If the chip lacks the .direction_input callback
                     * we logically assume all lines are outputs.
                     */
                    set_bit(FLAG_IS_OUT, &desc->flags);
```

Comment: P.S. The data sheet, in section 7.1, says that its i2c address is 0x48 - in reality it is 0x24.  The 7-bit binary value shown on the data sheet *is* 0x24.

Comment: Your answer mostly works.  After exporting a gpio, I can echo zeros and ones into `value` and they arrive in the module's `gc->set` method.  However, I *can* read the gpio from user-space (it always returns `0`).

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to do. Forbid reading? Reading actual state of output pin? Something else?

Comment: I had wanted to forbid reading.  In the mean time I realised that it would be easier to allow the reading of the last written value and have implemented that instead.

Comment: @chrisdew, that is exactly what I would do if I would be driver developer here.